# How to write own MPI_Bcast and MPI_reduce

Tags: c++, mpi

Is it possible to write own `Mpi_Bcast` and `Mpi_reduce` called it like `MyMpi_Bcast` and `MyMpi_Reduce`?
And have the same arguments like it has the real `Mpi_Bcast and Reduce`.

1.`int myMPI_Bcast( void *buffer, int count, MPI_Datatype datatype,int root, MPI_Comm comm);`

2.`int myMPI_Reduce( const void *sendbuf, void *recvbuf, int count,int root, MPI_Comm comm);`

My purpose is comparing the real `Mpi_Bcast` and own implementation? For example:

```
-— int test —-
My_MPI_Bcast: 50ms
MPI_Bcast: 34ms
```

Truthfully, I have searched some information for implementations of own `mpi_communicators`, and I can't find examples. Can you ,please, help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[This tutorial does exactly that.](http://mpitutorial.com/tutorials/mpi-broadcast-and-collective-communication/)

The linked tutorial is much more helpful, but for simplest `bcast` basically just have the originiating process send to all other processes.

For the most simple `reduce` have all processes send to one and the reciever combines the input in whatever method is specified.

Comment: Thank you so much for a link, really. It is very nice tutorial. As for `reduce` I can't understand, I understand that `mpi_reduce` gets the results after `bcast` but as for implementation..